# Import to .xls only 1 row of data from a sharepoint list (table)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

Good afternoon.
To keep data consistency, our single source of truth is an online sharepoint list with around 100 variables (columns) and now 2700 entries (rows)

For using in an .xls file, I would need to connect to 1 specific entry (1 row)  of this list based on an ID number and use its  content.
I can achieve this with the below queries but as the whole table is loaded each time, the refresh takes a lot of time and the file becomes big without any good reason for this.

Would it be possible to increase refresh time by loading only this specific line? how should I do this?
Thanks a lot
Best

```
Source = SharePoint.Tables("https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX", [Implementation=null, ApiVersion=15]),
#"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b766-71e3781e9f40" = Source{[Id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b766-71e3781e9f40"]} [Items],
#"Keep relevant row" = Table.SelectRows(#"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b766-71e3781e9f40",each [Id]=relevant number)
```

Stephane

See above the query which works but which still loads the whole table, which is an overkill

Answer (score 0):

You can try via SharePoint REST API:

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YourListName')/items(888)", [Headers=[Accept="application/json;odata=verbose"]]))
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer but I'm sorry to say that it sounds rather  Chinese to me.
Are you saying that my query should just be:

Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YourListName')/items()", [Headers=[Accept="application/json;odata=verbose"]]))

With 
yourlistname = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b766-71e3781e9f40"
item = how shall I here specify that I need the ID number which is in the 2nd column of the table )

Many thanks

Comment: Simply replace the first line of the code block you added in your own question, with what I provided in the answer. The other two lines are not necessary. You will need to replace `xxx`, `YourListName`, and `888` with what is needed. Let me know which bit you are stuck on. Replace `888` in `items(888)` with the required id number.

Comment: How did it go? Need any more on this?